# HTML text-box does't read data after spaces

Tags: python, html

Here is the sample code:

```
<form action= 'file.php'>
<br/><br/>

 Enter the numbers selected separated by a comma <input type = "text" 
 style="white-space:nowrap;" name= "number"> <br/>

<input type = "submit">
</form>
```

When the input is entered in the format:

> 2,3,4

I can parse it correctly. However if the user enters as:

> 2 ,3 ,4

(with space)
The back end python program just reads till the first whitespace.
Is there an option in HTML to ignore whitespace.

Python reads using:

> var=sys.argv

Comment: might help if you show us your python code

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use javascript to "clean" whitespace from user input before submitting.

```
<form action= 'file.php' onsubmit="cleanInput()">
<br/><br/>

 Enter the numbers selected separated by a comma <input type = "text" 
 style="white-space:nowrap;" name= "number"> <br/>

<input type = "submit">
</form>

<script>
function cleanInput() {
    var inp = document.getElementsByName("number")[0];
    inp.value = inp.value.replace(/\s/g, ""); // Clean whitespace
}
</script>
```

It would probably be better to read input with something else than `sys.argv` (I guess, that you call/pass arguments to python script directly with `popen` or something similar), but js can provide a quick fix.